# Identify this tree with thin trunk and large leaves?

Tags: identification, trees, tropical

I saw it at a resort in the Dominican Republic. I liked it because it seems to give decent shade but it doesn't seem to have a big trunk, so it's not heavy.

Can you guys identify this tree?
Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruffled fan palm tree (*Licuala grandis*)

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't realise you'd already id'd it... upvoting yours to make up for it!

Answer (score 6):

One of the fan palms, possibly Licuala grandis - gets up to 3 metres high over many years, likes tropical conditions, that is, reasonably high temperatures and high humidity

http://www.palmpedia.net/wiki/Licuala_grandis